# How to define the similar elevation points from 2 layers in the 4 nearests points?

Tags: qgis

I´m using QGIS 2.8.3. and I want to know what is the most similar elevation points value from a layer A to layer B in the 4 nearest points.
My layers have an attribute table with Long, Lat coordinates and elevation values. Any idea?

Comment: Please define what "similar" means to you.

Comment: Similar means less difference of elevation from point of layer A to 4 nearest points of layer B.

Comment: Should this return exactly one point? Sorry, still unclear.

Comment: Yes, I want to return the point that has less elevation difference of layer A from layer B.